# How to convert ptrdiff_t to int?

Tags: c++, regex

```
            std::wstring x = L"test test test foo";
            std::wregex regexp("test");

            std::ptrdiff_t match_count(std::distance(
                std::wsregex_iterator(x.begin(), x.end(), regexp),
                std::wsregex_iterator()));

            int n = 3 * match_count;
```

`match_count` returns how many matches the regex found.

But when i compile this example i get warnings like:

```
warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'ptrdiff_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

How i could convert a `ptrdiff_t` to `int` without "loss of data"?

Comment: You test `if(match_count > INT_MAX / 3)` and error out if true, otherwise you can safely cast it to an int and know that multiplying it by `3` will not overflow.

Comment: What kind of software are you coding? A web application, a compiler, or some embedded software? For what industries? Explain in written English what will happen to you if some data is lost.

Comment: `auto n = 3 * match_count;` would avoid the conversion, and thus the warning.

Comment: See if your iterator supplies a *difference_type* (it should) - That probably boils down to *ptrdiff_t* as well, but  you've shifted the problem to the library.

Answer (score 1):

> How i could convert a ptrdiff_t to int without "loss of data"?

By compiling for a system where int is large enough to represent all values of ptrdiff_t.

If you target a system where int is smaller than ptrdiff_t (which your target system is, as evidenced by the warning) then there is no way to prevent potential loss of data from such conversion.

By converting a larger integer type to a smaller one, there is always possibility for loss of data because a smaller type cannot possibly represent all the values that the larger one can represent.

Instead, you can avoid loss of data by not performing such conversion.

Answer (score -1):

> How i could convert a `ptrdiff_t` to `int` without "loss of data"?

On many implementations (e.g. Linux/x86-64 with C++ code compiled by [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) **you cannot avoid loss of data** since an `int` would have 32 bits, and a `ptrdiff_t` would have (like an `unsigned long`) 64 bits.

If avoiding loss of data is critically important (e.g. for safety critical embedded systems -like software inside health devices or aircraft guidance software, with [Common Criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Criteria) requirements...) I would add a runtime check.

Alternatively, try some [formal methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_methods) approach, like with [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/). That means make a proof that the loss of data don't happen.

Comment: The statement “you cannot avoid loss of data” is false. The compiler is not reporting there is or will be a loss of data. It is reporting the types involved admit a theoretical possibility of loss of data, and it is unable to prove or at least does not know that will not occur. But asserting that the author cannot avoid a loss of data confuses the limitations of the type system with what we can accomplish with program design…

Comment: … For example, in `int c; while (EOF != (c = getchar())) { unsigned char u = c; … }`, we know there is no loss of data in the conversion of `c` to `unsigned char`. Even though the type of `c` could represent a value that is not representable in `unsigned char`, this never occurs in execution of the initialization. Similarly, where a `ptrdiff_t` is returned due to the type design of the library routines being called, that does not mean they will return a value out of bounds for an `int` when the program used only data structures describable with `int` values.

Comment: Also, the mention of `unsigned long` in regard to `ptrdiff_t` is misleading; `ptrdiff_t` is signed.

Comment: I am not saying the OP should not use a run-time check, if that is appropriate for their situation. However, my general recommendation would be to use `ptrdiff_t` instead of `int`, avoiding the question in the first place. Failing that, if they do want to use `int` for some reason, another alternative is to prove that it suffices: analyze and document the code to show that, regardless of the `ptrdiff_t` type, the value being converted to `int` will always be representable. So, we have multiple ways to avoid loss of data; the assertion that we cannot is false.

Comment: Here’s more on why I think this answer and eerorika’s are on the wrong track: The compiler is not warning here because there is a potential for overflow or other loss of information. If that were the case, it would warn everywhere we had `x = x+1` or `x = x*x`. It is warning because the assignment of a wider type to a narrower type is not uncommonly a mistake by the programmer. So the issue here is not “you cannot avoid loss of data,” as that would also apply to `x+1` and `x*x`. The issue here is “Did you know what you are doing, and did you mean to do it?” That is what we need to teach.

Comment: (Of course, one should also know what one is doing with `x+1` and `x*x`. But it would be overwhelming for the compiler to warn on those. The message to take from the compiler warning is people not uncommonly make a mistake here, so please check it.)